# setting setViewName to same JSP page in different controllers in Spring

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I have a profile page where I get values from different controllers.

When I use `mv.setViewName("User_Profile")` in any of the controllers, I get values only from that controller on the JSP page.

Values from all other controllers do not appear when the page is accessed from any one of the controllers.

How can I make all values from all controllers to be visible on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Spring MVC ControllerAdvice to set the common properties:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-controller-advice

> Typically @ExceptionHandler, @InitBinder, and @ModelAttribute methods
>   apply within the @Controller class (or class hierarchy) they are
>   declared in. **If you want such methods to apply more globally, across
>   controllers, you can declare them in a class marked with
>   @ControllerAdvice or @RestControllerAdvice.**

So you create methods annotated with `@ModelAttribute` to set the common properties in your advice.

You can associate the ControllerAdvice with specific Controllers:

```
    @ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = {ProfileController1.class, ProfileController2.class})
    public class ProfileControllerAdvice{

    @ModelAttribute("someProperty")
    public String getSomeProperty(){
       return "I am can be accessed using ${someProperty} in the JSP.
    }
}
```